# Does root ownership and exclusive access imply encryption?

Tags: permissions, encryption, ownership

If I have a file with permissions and ownership like:
`-rw-------  1 root   root`, is this file encrypted?

I am asking this because I am wondering how the file is really protected against being read as plain bytes and then reconstructed by some non-root user, or by an attacker.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> is this file encrypted?

No. The file is still what the file is. If someone reboots into a live session the file is visible by ANY user that does the reboot. Same if someone takes out the harddisc and mounts it into another system where they are admin.

An encrypted file would be inaccessible however the method you would use.

All `-rw-------  1 root   root` does is make a file readable and writable by a user "root" and not by the group "root" and not by "others". Pretty strict but not good enough if you never want someone to pry into it.

The ONLY working method to prevent access by anyone on a system is not storing the file on that system.

Comment: "The ONLY working method to prevent access by anyone on a system is not storing the file on that system. " or encrypt it.

Comment: Nope. Encryption is NOT perfect. It has holes (intended and unintended). Plus when someone hacks your system and installs a program memory can be read while the file is processed. Encryption only stops to illiterate.

Comment: Encryption programs are not perfect. Encryption is "perfect" unless there is prior knowledge on the encrypted data (right?).

Comment: Yes. Stealing a key is also possible. Or using old techniques; 128- or 256-bit keys is not enough.  Thing is: the best protection comes from 1 single extra rule: if the system would lock up after X (where X is limited; 3 or 10) failed attempts encrypting with whatever method (even a 10-bit key would be enough) is going to stop a lot of people.

Comment: @MarcCayuelaRafols _"Encryption is "perfect" unless ..."_ - Encryption schemes (not implementations!) are, by and large, **not* perfect! Or at least, not provably so. For example, the Vigenère cipher is broken by design, as it is easily attacked with frequency analysis. As another example, DES has held up fairly well against such attacks, but its short keys (56bit) are easily brute-forced with modern resources, rendering it utterly broken in any practical sense. AES, the most widely used symmetric cipher today is doing well so far but we cannot _prove_ it has no flaws that render it breakable.

Comment: “Encryption is NOT perfect“ OK, but for all practical purposes it works quite well, using non broken ciphers and acceptable key lengths. One common caveat though is that most people do not realize FDE does not protect the data while the system is turned on.

Comment: In short: "The ONLY working method to prevent access by anyone on a system is not storing the file on that system. " All others methods have a least some sort of possibility of not being perfect. How slim the chance is, it is never 100%.

Comment: Again, that famous quote from Kevin Mitnick is surely intriguing, but if you want to work IRL you have to encrypt and store the files somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

No, just because a file is owned by e.g. `root` or a different user than yours does not encrypt it.

Depending on the file's permissions set for the owner, group and all others, the system will either grant or deny a user to access the file in a specific way. Of course, this protection only works against other processes, while the system is running and in control of all file I/O. You can read any file by simply booting a different operating system and mounting your disk.

Answer (score 7):

In short, **no**. File ownership and access permissions are a kind of access control. Encryption and access control are *orthogonal* (here meaning "independent") concepts. Both are methods to implement/enforce [authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization).

### [Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption)

means that only agents in possession of the decryption key can gain access to the decrypted "plain text" of a file or data object. This access can be (temporarily) *extended* to other agents, e. g. users of the same system that holds the decryption key in memory.

### [Access Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control)

means that an authority, e. g. an operating system running on a computer, decides who gets which kind of access to which resource (which may be a file, data object, or something else).

### Why are they independent?

An operating system may know how to decrypt an encrypted data object to gain access to its plain text but that doesn't mean that it extends this access to all its users. It will commonly use access control databases to decide to whom to extend access (if at all).

Conversely, a user may have access to an encrypted dataset but, lacking a valid decryption key, cannot make any sense of it, i. e. cannot access its plain text. (This is not currently possible with any of the file systems and file system tools shipped with Ubuntu but such features are in development for out-of-the-box Ubuntu in the form of new ext4 features and already available in other file systems, e. g. ZFS and NTFS, albeit not necessarily on Linux.)