# How to run script at startup that requires a password?

Tags: security, chmod

I am running ubutu on a [raspbery pi 3](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/)

I have a script that runs as root when ubuntu boots. For that script to run correctly I need a password. In other words my script starts like:

```
#!/bin/bash

myPassword=(cat /root/foo/psw.txt)  # get password from disk
....
... etc
```

I have protected my password by running:

```
sudo chown root:root /root/foo/psw.txt
sudo chmod 700 /root/foo/psw.txt
```

Thanks to that command only the root user can read the file `/root/foo/psw.txt`.

But according to this question:

[Does root ownership and exclusive access imply encryption?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001384/does-root-ownership-and-exclusive-access-imply-encryption)

that means that if someone where to take the sd card and read from the disk they will find the password on plain text!

**So my question is how can I pass the password to my script securely so that if someone where to read from the sd card they will not find the password?**

From reading and researching on the internet everyone says to not store the password.

So is the solution to download the password? If I download the password that means someone else can download the password. Lets say I download the password and it is encrypted. I will have to store another password to unencrypt that file and I will be left with another password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does root ownership and exclusive access imply encryption?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001384/does-root-ownership-and-exclusive-access-imply-encryption)

Comment: What do you need the password for? What is it a password to?

Comment: To make outbound calls. I am using the raspberry pi as a pbx system

Answer (score 0):

I have a server `A` and my raspberry pi `B`. People have access to `B` but not to `A`. In other words server `A` is on the cloud whereas the raspberry pi is on an office building. This are the steps to solve the problem:

1. Generate a public and private key on server `A`.

   `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`
2. Install SSH on rapberry pi `B` and place the public key generated on step 1 (id_rsa.pub) into

   `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`

   (not that authorized_keys is a file NOT a directory and it contains the public key)
3. Permit ssh login ONLY using RSA on `B`

   `PasswordAuthentication no
    RSAAuthentication yes
    AuthorizedKeysFile   /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`
4. Now `A` can access `B` without storing any passwords on `B`

   `ssh -i </path/to/privateKey> root@raspberryPiIpAddress`
5. So when `B` boots it will send a notification to `A`. `A` then will crate a secure ssh connection into `B`. `A` will send the commands that needs to be executed by `B` through ssh.